# Dragging and dropping sprites without hardcoding names using swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, ios8, skspritenode, sknode

I'm just trying to have the user drag and drop certain sprites around the screen.  The answers I saw for this are checking the name of the sprite (something like below).   There must be a better way to do this.  Thanks for any input.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    var nodeTouched = SKNode()
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        nodeTouched = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

        if(nodeTouched.name? == "character") {
            character.position=location
            currentNodeTouched = nodeTouched
        } else {
            currentNodeTouched.name = ""
        }
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        var nodeTouched = SKNode()
        nodeTouched = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

        if(currentNodeTouched.name == "character") {
            character.position = location
        }
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        var nodeTouched = SKNode()
        nodeTouched = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

        if(currentNodeTouched.name == "character") {
            character.position = location
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to drag and drop only specific sprites, there has to be a way of identifying them. This can be anything that can be used to distinguish the nodes. The following are a few suggestions on what can be used in this context.

The code in the answer is in Objective-C, hope you can translate it to Swift.

**The `name` property**

As you said, this is the most commonly used way of determining whether the sprite can be dragged or not.

**The `userData` property**

This is a property associated with SKNode which lets you set any custom data you want. You can read about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/userData).

```
[node.userData setValue:@(YES) forKey:@"draggable"]; //Setting the value

if ([[node.userData valueForKey:@"draggable"] boolValue]) //Checking the value
```

**Subclassing**

You can also create a custom class which can either handle the deag-drop functionality on it's own or implement a BOOL as a property which can be checked in the touch delegates.

**Class name**

In some cases, you might want only the nodes of a specific class to be dragged.

```
if ([node isKindOfClass:[CustomNode class]])

if ([(NSStringFromClass([node class]) isEqualToString:@"CustomNode"])
```